# Getting recipients value from a table to send an email in SSIS Job

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS job which sends an email after the successful completion. I have hard coded the recipients email addresses but I want to get the value for recipients from a table via a query or stored procedure. Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: this look nice http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s437/ssis-email.htm

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

I'll assume you know how to execute SQL within SSIS.

You need to run an ExecuteSQL task with an output parameter that is populated by your query.

That parameter is then used by your email task.

[Detailed Instructions.](http://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2012/08/how-to-set-and-use-variables-in-ssis-execute-sql-task/)